# Call function inside event handler oop

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

How to call method Go from inside a event handler?

```
function Test()
{
    this.yo = "YO";

    this.Go = function()
    {
       alert(this.yo);        
    }

    $(".aha").click(function()
    {
          //Call Go();        
    });
}

var test = new Test();
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BkNfY/9/

Comment: @TusharGupta Wow, don't impose your coding style on somebody else's question. That was a totally inappropriate edit.

Comment: another option:  .click(function(){  this.Go()  } .bind(this)); i like that since e.target will refer to the "old this", aka the element being clicked. you can also just do .click( this.Go.bind(this) );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common method is to have a local variable in your constructor that is a reference to the instance:

```
function Test()
{
    var self = this;

    this.yo = "YO";

    this.Go = function(){
       alert(this.yo);        
    }

    $(".aha").click(function(){
          self.Go();        
    });
}
```

Or you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function you pass to `.click()`:

```
    $(".aha").click(function(){
          this.Go();        
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: By way of explanation: `this` is a somewhat magical variable that cannot be closed over, so the context is lost in your click handler. You need to set it aside in a variable that *can* be closed over, and one of the very common ways of doing this is with a variable called `self`. There is nothing magic about this variable, it's just a somewhat common convention.

Comment: Isnt self itself a global context identifier?

Comment: @bergman - Um...yes. But in this case it's a local variable since it's declared inside a function with `var` (if needed the same function could reference the global one with `window.self`). Feel free to use some other name...

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/BkNfY/12/

```
function Test(){
    var that = this;

    that.yo = "YO";

    that.go = function(){
       alert(that.yo);        
    }

    $(".aha").click(function(){
       that.go();        
    });

    return that;
}

var test = new Test();
```

but it would make more sense to do it like this: (if you want to reuse Test)

```
function Test(){
    var that = this;

    that.yo = "default YO";

    that.go = function(){
       alert(yo);        
    }

    return that;
}

var test = new Test();
test.yo = "YO";

$(".aha").click(function(){
     test.go();        
});
```

You could keep yo "private" if it is not going to be used outside of Test, e.g. test.yo

```
function Test(){
    var that = this,
        yo = "YO"; // yo is now "private"
                   // so can't modify yo from outside of this function

    that.go = function(){
       alert(yo);        
    }

    return that;
}

var test = new Test();

$(".aha").click(function(){
     test.go();        
});
```

Comment: There's no need to add the `return` statement. Also, why is `yo` suddenly a private variable?

Comment: @nnnnnn `yo` is still an instance variable in that it is bound to a specific instance of a `Test`.

Comment: @meagar - Yes, but what I meant is that you can't use `test.yo`. I've edited my comment to say "private" instead of "instance".

Comment: @nnnnnn No, it's "private" in that sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn "There's no need to add the return statement." - I agree, in this example not needed. Just a habbit, in case if we do e.g. that = new SuperTest(). I made yo "private" to give OP something more to think about, as he is going towards classical approach, and I thought he might find it useful. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way :

```
$('.aha').click($.proxy(function (e) {
    // e.target refers to the clicked element
    this.Go();
}, this));
```

Shorter :

```
$('.aha').click($.proxy(this.Go, this));
$('.aha').click($.proxy(this, 'Go'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/